# Transparent Cube For Character

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

how to make a **transparent cube** so that my **character** *walks inside* a *building* or *house* and you can see the interior partially, where my character is walking ?

in the reference image i make a blender render with transparency

1. the house is complete no have cuts
2. the character is inside the house
3. the cube is transparent

**NOTE:**
Now ... I have a basic idea to start from, but I do not know if BGE accepts the same form that I use to render, since I use a Boolean Difference modifier, and I do not know completely if these modifiers can be applied to blender game engine

*I have seen it in some YouTube videos but I do not know if it is in BGE, and I would like to know if I can do it, it would be great, in logic bricks please, preferably, I'm still a python brute, I have a hard time not thinking about c / c ++*
[image: Reference Image]
[reference Link reading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20858/how-do-i-cut-something-in-the-game-engine)
[image: Little animation]

Comment: i found this, is correct ???
[Boolean modifier in game engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9136/boolean-modifier-in-game-engine)

Comment: No you can't use boolean modifier in bge nor do any other engines do realtime boolean operations for the effect. The transparency is shader code that clips rendering of the surface by a given formula such as if the point is inside a given axis aligned box or close enough to given 3d position.

Comment: @kheetor so how can I achieve this effect in BGE? any idea or suggestion ?!, About 3 months ago I saw a video on YouTube referring to this and today I can not find it to show here to see if someone has an idea of how they did it, on the other hand, in the link that I put in the 1st comment I understand that yes but that only has effect between the two meshes related to Boolean

Comment: If it was on blender it was probably used in an animation and not bge. I'm not up to date on what's possible on bge these days but I believe you can write your own shaders.

Comment: yes, but is very hard :P, i programmer but i rookie in game development area

Comment: You do not need to cut through the house. Break your house into several fitting parts (like lego blocks). Make these parts transparent on demand (e.g. when they are blocking the line of sight). This way you just care about the part rather than the whole house.

Comment: this makes my idea very difficult
It is a fundamental principle to develop my idea
I will try to explain it, my English is not very good but I will use more images to copy it

imagine that the transparent cube is your field of vision and when you walk the cube that surrounds the character will only let you see the area that delimits, when you enter a building you will see a part and not everything, because you will find zombie enemies that will they will attack surprisingly.

Comment: So for this reason I do not want to use transparent walls, I really saw it done, but I do not know if it was HELLO MY NAME IS GAVIN videos, but someone or for some reason your channel was deleted and I could not find that video there are others but I still can not find them

Comment: @MonsterI will make a small animation this week to illustrate the idea of how it should work

Comment: @Monster Hi, I put a small animation in a gif of what I'm looking to do

Comment: Thanks for the animation. Unfortunately this is very very hard to implement with the BGE as you need to preserve texture coordinates and add surfaces (at the edge of the visibility change). As said, you can split the walls into smaller parts and change the visibility/transparency when the character is near.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this effect using material nodes, a mesh, a spot lamp, and a camera.

## Blend-File (made in UPBGE 0.2x)

https://blend-exchange.com/b/bOl2J557

## Explanation

When the spot lamp's shadow, which is casted by the mesh, hits the surface of the building, the casted shadow will act as an alpha (transparency) mask for the building.

## Screenshot (nodes setup)

[image]

## Tutorial

https://youtu.be/4Seqm826oWk

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post.  External links are good as supplemental information, but the answer should stand on its own as a source for the full implementation of the process.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. How do you suggest I edit my answer to better fit the question?

By include a screenshot of the node setup perhaps?

Comment: A screenshot and accompanying description would work great

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my post with additional information.